# != null VS ?.let { } performance for immutable variables in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, null-check

From what I understand, the big advantage of `?.let{}` over `!= null` is it guarantees that a mutable value is not changed inside the block.

However, in case of an immutable variable is there a performance difference?

For example, I have a simple method

```
private fun test() {
    val x: String? = ""

    if (x != null) {
        print("test")
    }

    x?.let {
        print("test")
    }

}
```

When I see the resulting Kotlin Bytecode it seems that for let it has much more code.

**For the x != null case:**

```
    LINENUMBER 8 L1
   L2
    LINENUMBER 9 L2
    LDC "test"
    ASTORE 2
   L3
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.print (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L4
   L5
```

**For x?.let { } case it is:**

```
    LINENUMBER 12 L5
    ALOAD 1
    ASTORE 2
   L6
   L7
    ALOAD 2
    ASTORE 3
   L8
    ICONST_0
    ISTORE 4
   L9
    LINENUMBER 13 L9
    LDC "test"
    ASTORE 5
   L10
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    ALOAD 5
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.print (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   L11
   L12
    LINENUMBER 14 L12
   L13
    NOP
   L14
    LINENUMBER 12 L14
   L15
    NOP
   L16
```

If I decompile to java then the resulting code seems similar with one more variable being assigned for let (curiously an int variable is set to false)

For x != null:

```
  String var2 = "test";
  System.out.print(var2);
```

For x?.let { }

```
  int var4 = false;
  String var5 = "test";
  System.out.print(var5);
```

In the end, my question is: Is there a performance different between let and `!=` for immutable variables?

Comment: This is a case of micro optimisation - difference is so minuscule You'd have hard time even measuring it. Just use whatever is more readable in the context.

Comment: @Pawel: Agreed.  The big performance wins come from avoiding unnecessary: synchronisation/threading, algorithmic complexity, network/file/DB I/O, temporary objects, and (to a lesser extent) main memory access.  The optimisation here doesn't reduce any of those, so in practice it's never going to make any practical difference.  In fact, the JVM will probably optimise it out, anyway.

Comment: I just see way too many lines in the decompiled version but I can't read what it is, that's why I was wondering!

Answer (score 1):

The two statements are not really equivalent. The outcome is obviously the same in your two examples, but `let` is a [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) and thus is doing a bit more lifting than simple flow control.

From the linked documentation:

> The Kotlin standard library contains several functions whose sole purpose is to execute a block of code within the context of an object. When you call such a function on an object with a lambda expression provided, it forms a temporary scope.

For example even if you're not using the `it` in your example, this context with the it-variable is still created and that bears some overhead with it.

However, as others have pointed out I think this is a case where it's better to optimize the code for readability over speed in this case. In cases where a let allows for more readable code (which IMO is usually the case), that's a bigger win than the miniscule performance gain you may get from using an if instead.

Comment: it's worth noting that `let` is an inline function, meaning that it inlines both itself as well as the lambda call. If that wasn't the case, there would be an arguably significant overhead for using `let` instead of a simple `if`. Luckily, all scope functions in Kotlin are `inline`